# Audio Manipulation

Tags: python, audio

I'm looking for a Python library that will allow me to record, manipulate, and merge audio files. Most of the ones I've seen don't support Windows and/or are outdated. Does anyone have any suggestions for libraries or how these functions could be implemented with the standard python library?

Comment: What type of sound files?  WAV?  MP3?  OGG?  Something else?  In any case, do an internet search for "python ffmpeg"

Comment: And you did an internet search for "Python OGG", right? :)

Comment: Didn't find much, I've been trying exactly that before posting the problem. Found a few command line tools, not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording and Manipulating are generally different problems.  For both of these, I stick with .wav file formats since (at least in their simpler forms) they are basically just the raw data with a minimal header and are easy to work with.

Recording: I use `pyaudio`, which provides bindings to the `portaudio` library.

Manipulation: For simple things I use `audioop` which is included in the basics Python installation, and for more complex things I go straight to `scipy` (which can read in many .wav files with `scipy.io.wavfile.read`) and then manipulate the data like any other time-series data.  `scipy` is powerful and fast, but doesn't offer many audio specific tools nor does it present things in an audio specific terminology.

There are other things out there, though less well established, such as Snack, Audiere, and AudioLazy, are tools I've heard of bet never used, and I don't know which are still available, or their level of development, etc.